# Rookie mistake with join

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I believe I have made a rookie mistake with the last join but I cannot see what it is. The code worked until I needed to add the last entry recorded in the DONCOMMS table. (This table contains all the communications for each donor) Now I get 3 duplicate lines for every entry from the first table.

The original report shows me all the donor pledges from DON0010 and links the area description and donor from the tables AREA and DON0001 respectively. I now want to bring out the latest communication found in DONCOMMS for each pledge found in DON0010.

```
select
 pl.[PLEDGE_NO]
,d1.[DONOR_NO]
,rtrim(pl.DONOR) DONOR
,d1.[CONTACT_NAME]
,d1.[AREA1]
,a1.[DESCRIPTION] 
,pl.[AMOUNT]
,pl.[AMOUNT_RECVD]
,pl.[TYPE]
,ISNULL(t2.[COMM_TYPE],'') AS COMM_TYPE
,ISNULL(t2.[REFERENCE],'') AS REFERENCE
,ISNULL(t2.[DETAIL],'') AS DETAIL
,replace(isnull(convert(varchar, t2.[DATE], 103),''),'01/01/1753','') COMMS_DATE
,ISNULL(t2.[CONTACT],'') AS CONTACT
from don0010 pl    
left join DON0001 d1 on pl.[DONOR] = d1.[DONOR]  
left join AREA1 a1 on d1.[AREA1] = a1.[AREA]
**left join (Select * from doncomms dc where dc.DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE)    FROM doncomms WHERE DONOR_NO = dc.DONOR_NO) and ENTITY = 'C') t2
on t2.[DONOR_NO] = d1.[DONOR_NO]**
```

Comment: What data is on doncomms? We need something more than `this doesnt work` explanation. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Could you provide the sample data for the table doncomms

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   pl.[PLEDGE_NO]
  ,d1.[DONOR_NO]
  ,rtrim(pl.DONOR) DONOR
  ,d1.[CONTACT_NAME]
  ,d1.[AREA1]
  ,a1.[DESCRIPTION] 
  ,pl.[AMOUNT]
  ,pl.[AMOUNT_RECVD]
  ,pl.[TYPE]
  ,ISNULL(t2.[COMM_TYPE],'') AS COMM_TYPE
  ,ISNULL(t2.[REFERENCE],'') AS REFERENCE
  ,ISNULL(t2.[DETAIL],'') AS DETAIL
  ,replace(isnull(convert(varchar, t2.[DATE], 103),''),'01/01/1753','') COMMS_DATE
  ,ISNULL(t2.[CONTACT],'') AS CONTACT
from don0010 pl    
left join DON0001 d1 on pl.[DONOR] = d1.[DONOR]  
left join AREA1 a1 on d1.[AREA1] = a1.[AREA]
outer apply
(
  select top 1 with ties dc.* 
  from doncomms dc
  where dc.DONOR_NO = d1.DONOR_NO and dc.ENTITY = 'C'
  order by dc.DATE desc
) t2
```

Comment: Thank you Ivan, however this code brings out more rows (33271) than there are in DON0010 (31590)

Comment: @JohnSullivan that means some of `don0010` rows have more than one corresponding row in any of joined tables. Try removing (commenting) joined tables from query one by one to locate problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it works untill I use the _outer apply_

Comment: @JohnSullivan, which means you have several rows with "max" date. I thought this is exactly what you want - to find all rows from `doncomms` with maximum date. If it is not and your objective is to get only one row from `outer apply` then you need `top 1` without option `with ties`. I'd suggest to append additional column to `order by` clause because there are many rows with the same date but you need exactly one. If you don't specify additional sorting column - you may obtain different `top 1` row from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem usually is you have several rows with `DATE = MAX(DATE)`

Try this query alone to find out if same `DONOR_NO` appear more than once

```
Select DONOR_NO, count(*)
from doncomms dc 
where dc.DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE)    
                 FROM doncomms 
                 WHERE DONOR_NO = dc.DONOR_NO) 
 and ENTITY = 'C'
GROUP BY DONOR_NO
```

In that case is better if you use a `CTE` syntaxis and `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
WITH cte as (
     SELECT *
     FROM (
             SELECT *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DONOR_NO ORDER BY DATE DESC) as rn
             FROM doncomms 
             WHERE ENTITY = 'C'
          ) T
     WHERE T.rn = 1
)
select *
from don0010 pl    
left join DON0001 d1 on pl.[DONOR] = d1.[DONOR]  
left join AREA1 a1 on d1.[AREA1] = a1.[AREA]
left join cte as t2
on t2.[DONOR_NO] = d1.[DONOR_NO]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Juan, I just needed to add the field names to run as a view.

```
WITH cte as (  
 SELECT *
 FROM (
         SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DONOR_NO ORDER BY DATE DESC) as rn
         FROM doncomms 
         WHERE ENTITY = 'C'
      ) T
 WHERE T.rn = 1
)
select   pl.[PLEDGE_NO]
,d1.[DONOR_NO]
,rtrim(pl.DONOR) DONOR
,d1.[CONTACT_NAME]
,d1.[AREA1]
,a1.[DESCRIPTION] 
,pl.[AMOUNT]
,pl.[AMOUNT_RECVD]
,pl.[TYPE]
,pl.[SOURCE]
,d1.[POST_CODE] as DONOR_POSTCODE   
,replace(isnull(convert(varchar, pl.PLEDGE_DATE, 103),''),'01/01/1753','') PLEDGE_DATE  
,replace(isnull(convert(varchar, pl.[EVENT_DATE], 103),''),'01/01/1753','') EVENT_DATE
,rtrim(pl.DESCRIPTION1) DESCRIPTION1
,rtrim(pl.DESCRIPTION2) DESCRIPTION2
,pl.[COMPLETE]
,pl.[APPLICATION]
,rtrim(pl.COMMENT1) COMMENT1 
,rtrim(pl.COMMENT2) COMMENT2
,pl.[MEMO] 
,ISNULL(t2.[ENTERED_BY] , '') AS ENTERED_BY
,ISNULL(t2.[COMM_TYPE],'') AS COMM_TYPE
,ISNULL(t2.[REFERENCE],'') AS REFERENCE
,ISNULL(t2.[DETAIL],'') AS DETAIL
,replace(isnull(convert(varchar, t2.[DATE], 103),''),'01/01/1753','') COMMS_DATE
,ISNULL(t2.[CONTACT],'') AS CONTACT
from don0010 pl    
left join DON0001 d1 on pl.[DONOR] = d1.[DONOR]  
left join AREA1 a1 on d1.[AREA1] = a1.[AREA]
left join cte as t2
on t2.[DONOR_NO] = d1.[DONOR_NO]
```